# How to Autoshrink UILabel?

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel, auto, shrink

I have tried following multiple instructions to get a dynamic font-size according to the size of the screen, but to no avail. In this example,

I have one `UILabel` that has the following constraints:

- Equal Width to Superview
- Align Center X to Safe Area
- Align Center Y to Superview

And yet, when I run the project on a simulator of two different screen sizes, the font size won't change. What am I missing?

Here are photos of the attributes on the `UILabel`, and the results on simulators for the iPhone XR and iPhone 5s.

[image: Attributes on UILabel]

[image: Results]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question right, but autoshrink starts working if the content of the UILabel has to be condensed for the available space. As you allow multiple lines (Lines == 0) IOS has plenty of space to display and has no need to shrink.

Answer (score 2):

`UILabel`s can shrink their font sizes automatically if you set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to true.

Not sure if that solves your problem. If it doesn't and you want a more flexible solution, where you want the text to enlarge when the label enlarges, you can try `FittableFontLabel`: https://github.com/tbaranes/FittableFontLabel

You just make your `UILabel` to be of type `FittableFontLabel` and remember to set `lineBreakMode` to `wordWrap`:

[image]